# userform change backcolor every control

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I'm writing a process to change the back color of every control when the new data is entered. My code works no problem when the control is empty. But doesn't work when I start to enter value or select value from combobox. Besides, the process doesn't work for DateTimePicker.
Can any guru help me? Thank you so much!

```
Public Sub Control_Change()
    Dim ctrl As Control
    Dim ans As Long
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If ctrl.Name <> "cboProjectHealth" Then
            Select Case True
                Case TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.CheckBox, TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.OptionButton
                    Select Case ctrl.Value
                        Case True
                            ctrl.BackColor = vbWhite
                        Case Else
                            ctrl.BackColor = vbBlue: ans = ans + 1
                    End Select
                Case TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.TextBox, TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.ComboBox
                    Select Case ctrl.Value
                        Case vbNullString
                            ctrl.BackColor = vbBlue: ans = ans + 1
                        Case Else
                            ctrl.BackColor = vbWhite
                    End Select
                 Case TypeOf ctrl Is DTPicker
                    Select Case ctrl.Value
                        Case vbNullString
                            ctrl.CalendarBackColor = vbBlue: ans = ans + 1
                        Case Else
                            ctrl.CalendarBackColor = vbWhite
                    End Select
            End Select
        End If
    Next ctrl
End Sub
```

Comment: (1) we cannot help if you don't show your code. (2) "*doesn't work*" is a completely useless error description. (3) read [ask] and improve your question by [edit]ing it.

Comment: Well if it doesnt work for date/time picker did you look up the properties of that control? might seem to me the answer lies in whether or not that is an option for that control.

Comment: Another comment I might add is maybe youre not putting your change function/sub in the appropriate event. Did you try "after update"?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thank you for your reply. This is the first time that I seek for help on this site. I was about update the code when you replied me. I didn't learn programming in English and it's been over ten years that I didn't write programs.  lol

Comment: @DougCoats Hi Thank you a lot. The date/time picker has CalendaBackColor property. But it doesn't even work when I change it manually. I didn't write VBA with my bare hands ever since college. All I know is to search codes online and adjust them per needs. lol.. I'll try with your idea, although I'm not familiar with Events at all.

Comment: The problem is you still did't explain what "*doesn't work*" means. Please explain what your code actually does when you run it, what you expect it to do instead, where you got errors and which. You also might read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) and add a question to your post.